How do I solve ubuntu boot error for failed to start service?
I tried to install v2ray on ubuntu. After restarting it couldn't finish boot. It show a failed error :
Failed to start v2ray.service
To repair, I used ubuntu boot flash, then installed and ran boot-repair program, but the problem still remains.

Did you check and see if the maker of this app have any kind of support?

The mentioned Error message "Failed to start v2ray.service" indicates that the v2ray service failed to start. It can be due to reasons such as invalid configurations or missing dependencies. Boot into recovery mode of the ubuntu:
Check status using!
systemctl status v2ray.service

For more details run
journalctl -xe --unit=v2ray.service

Check whether firewall is preventing the service or not, and ensure that file (/etc/v2ray/config.json) is correctly formatted and contains valid settings as incorrect configurations can prevent v2ray from starting.
Use installation guides like v2ray installation or Install v2ray or use an official guide
